# Flickering light reflection issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, reflection

As you can see [here](https://youtu.be/lebIC8UtDwg), I've had an issue with my render. The mountains in the background seem to reflect the light sources in my scene strangely, which leads to this weird flickering.

specs:
AMD Ryzen 5 3500X,
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti,
16GB DDR4 RAM,
Windows 10,
Used Blender version: 3.5
Used render engine: Cycles

---

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

There are no overlapping geometry, as the mountain is flat in Material preview.

The mountains were made using the blendpeaks add-on.
Material Setup [image: Color] and [image: Displacement]

(Unfortunately I can't provide a decimated version of my file, as the blend-exchange site only accepts files below 30MB and my file still uses 43MB after removing everything unnecessary)

Edit: Thanks for all the answers. I finally managed to fix the problem by turning off Glossy and Transmission in the Ray Visibility Tab in the Object Properties. [image: Screenshot])

Comment: Could be Z-fighting. Check if you have overlapping geometry in the mountains.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Thx for adding more info to your question, although still very scarce. How are the mountains generated, with displacement? Please show the material setup. Best would be to upload a reduced/minimal version of your file which reproduces the flickering https://blend-exchange.com/